# How to join only the most recent record in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables A and B. Table A can have multiple records for each user. Table B can have multiple records for each row in table A.

Here is an example:

```
    Table A                 Table B
   a_id   a_key        b_id   b_key  b_AtblID
1. 6678   5778      1. 6509    5778    6678
2. 6679   5778      2. 6508    5778    6678
                    3. 6507    5778    6679
                    4. 6505    5778    6679
                    5. 6490    5778    6678
```

You can see 2 records in A table. One record has 3 records in B table and one have 2 records in B table.

I want my query to pull records from table A and the most recent record from B table. I don't need every single record from Table B that is matching record in table A if that makes sense. Here is example of what I have but my code pulled all records from table B:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN B
        ON b_AtblID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 b_AtblID
            FROM B 
            WHERE b_AtblID = a_id
            ORDER BY b_id DESC
        )
```

I was hoping that my code will return only one record for each row on table A but I got all records from table B. If anyone can help please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is that you have a many to many relationship between these two tables. This causes lots of challenges. It would be better if this utilized a bridge table to manage that relationship. Are you able to fix the design?

Comment: b_id is primary key for B table. I can't change my table architecture. This is an old system that I have to maintain...

Comment: what is your criteria for most recent record? `max` `b_id`?

Comment: I feel your pain. Your best bet is to use something like Lamak's answer below.

Comment: Just to pull the highest b_id since I don't have any other field. Create date exist but can be the same for multiple records if they are created on the same date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b_AtblID ORDER BY b_id DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableB
)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA a
INNER JOIN CTE b
    ON a.a_id = b.b_AtblID
    AND b.RN = 1
;
```

Or `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM dbo.TableB
             WHERE b_AtblID = a.a_id
             ORDER BY b_id DESC) b;
```

Comment: I think you need to extend the Window function: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_key, b_AbtlID ORDER BY b_id)`

Comment: @Tyron78 as I understood the question, I don't see the need

Comment: I have tried cross apply solution but keep getting an error Incorrect syntax near ';'

Comment: @espresso_coffee I left out the derived table alias, try now

Comment: That works! It seems that Cross Apply is not that fast, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @espresso_coffee that's why I posted more than one way to do it, so you can test which one works better for you

Comment: Thank you, I will do some research.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #tempA (a_id int,a_key int)
Create table #tempB (b_id int,b_key int,b_abtlid int)
Insert into #tempA values(6678,5778),(6679,5778)
Insert into #tempB values(6509,5778,6678),(6508,5778,6678),(6507,5778,6679),(6505,5778,6679),(6490,5778,6678)


select a_id,a_key,b_id,b_abtlid from (
select *,row_number() over(partition by a_id order by b_id desc )as Rn from #tempA a
inner join #tempB b
on a.a_id=b.b_abtlid ) t 
where t.Rn=1
```